# (Unity ML-agent) What is the best way to observe the environment on a curved terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent

Currently, For checking the objects on the slope, I'm using the RayPerceptionSensor3D component, increasing "EndVerticleOffset" variable by one every frame. But, I think this method seems to have a lot of overhead. is there a better way?